# Usage of adverbs like reasonably, practically, essentially, ridiculously, basically

Tags: word-usage, adverbs

I have recently noticed a phenomenon in English that seems quite common.  The phenomenon is regarding the usage of certain adverbs:

- *Practically* should mean *in a practical manner*.  But it is often used to mean *almost* or *mostly*: e.g. "She was practically fainting from lack of air."
- *Essentially* should mean *in essence* or *in an essential manner*.  But it is also often used to mean *almost* or *mostly*: e.g. "I am essentially done with my courses this semester"; "He was essentially an adult although he was technically a child."
- *Reasonably* should mean *in a reasonable manner* but it is used to mean *quite* or *somewhat*: e.g. "The food was reasonably good", or "She remained reasonably calm despite her fear."
- *Ridiculously* should mean *in a ridiculous way* but it is often used to mean *extremely* or *overly*.
- *Basically* should mean *in a basic or fundamental sense* but it is often used to mean *almost* or *mostly*.

There does seem to be some sense to this.  For instance, when I say "I am essentially done with my courses this semester", what I might mean is that *in essence* I am done.  But in casual use, I don't think most people think of it this way.  If I say "I'm essentially finished eating" I don't mean to suggest that I am finished in some essential way, or that I have some essential property *as if* I were finished.  Rather, I mean "I'm almost finished eating."  Similarly, "She remained reasonably calm" suggests that she was quite calm, not necessarily that her calmness was reasonable or rational.  If I wanted to say that her calmness was rational, I would have said "she remained rational and stayed calm".

My questions are:

1. Does this phenomenon have a name?  There seem to be a lot of adverbs that are used in this way.
2. Is this usage correct, or should one only use adverbs like *practically, reasonably, basically* when they can actually be substituted with *practically speaking*, *in a reasonable way*, and *in a basic manner*?

Comment: I totally get your confusion. This is basically *informal speech*, and it's literally impossible to prevent. Some of your uses, though, are way less idiomatic than others. Is it correct? Absolutely! Does it have a name? I dunno. Hyperbole? Slang? Butchering of the language? Maybe someone knows a better answer.

Comment: I think your basic assumptions may be wrong. *practically* as used here means *for all practical purposes.*   *essentially* means *at it's essence*  and *basically* means *at it's base* which makes it practically  the same as essentially.

Comment: @Jim I see what you are saying, and I tried to address that in my paragraph beginning "There does seem...".  I don't have any issue with these phrases when they are used in the way you say, but I believe in practice many people forget that "practically" is short for "for all practical purposes" and simply use it to mean "almost" or "mostly".  I'm asking if there is a name for that sort of usage, and if it is correct.

Comment: Perhaps you're thinking of hyperbole?

Comment: Some of these are metaphoric. _ridiculously_ means _extremely_ because excess is often ridiculous.

Comment: The second definition of _reasonably_ is _to a moderate or acceptable degree; fair; quite_.

Comment: Who are you to decide what a word *should* mean?

Comment: @Clare Ironically, it is you and not me who insisted on a single meaning of a word: namely, you assumed by *should* I meant some sort of moral should, when I really meant "would be expected to". For example, when I said practically "should" mean "in a practical manner", I simply meant that when I think of the meaning of the word *practically* that is what I expect its meaning to be. So really, I don't get how you're so quick to jump on me and moreover how you missed the entirety of what I was saying in this question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In each of the example sentences of the OP, someone **chose** a word that *approximated* a more complex **thought**, and **presented** the language in a sentence. Then someone reads the word, and chooses an **interpretation** of the speaker's thought. In some examples, the OP *interpretation* may be closer than others. Only the original writer could confirm the actual meaning, but allow me to suggest a **possible** **meaning** for each adverb that shows how the usage was

essentially,

basically,

reasonably and

practically correct:

---

The original adverb **choice** builds on a root **meaning**. It replaces the complex **thought**, answering an adverbial query:

> "She was ***practically*** fainting from lack of air."

- **Choice**:"*Practically* from *practice*;
- **Meaning**:"*In practice*" with reference to *What was the practice of her fainting?*
- **Thought**: She was fainting "*in every practice except loosing consciousness*"..."
- **Interpretation**: She ***almost*** fainted; if she had fainted, we would have left out *practically*.

---

> "He was ***essentially*** an adult, although he was technically a
>   child."

- **Choice**: *Essentially* from *essential*
- **Meaning**: "*In essence*" with reference to *What is essential to being an adult?*
- **Thought**: He was "*delaying gratification*", although he was technically a child.
- **Interpretation**: He is ***almost*** an adult; if he were 18, we might have used *actually*.

---

> "She remained ***reasonably*** calm despite her fear."

- **Choice**: *Reasonably* from *reasonable*
- **Meaning**: "within ability to reason" with reference to *What calm remains within the ability to reason in spite of her fear?*
- **Thought**: She remained calm "*within my ability to reason*" despite her fear.
- **Interpretation**: She remained ***quite*** calm, with ***quite*** meaning *to a certain  extent*. [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/quite)

---

> "The price was ***ridiculously*** cheap"

- **Choice**: *Ridiculously* from *ridiculous*
- **Meaning**: "*to a ridiculous extent*" with reference to *What is ridiculous about a cheap price?*
- **Thought**: The cheap prices was "*ridiculously extreme*".
- **Interpretation**: The price is ***extremely*** cheap.

---

> He ***basically*** totaled his car in the accident.

- **Choice**: *Basically* from *basic*
- **Meaning**: "*at the base*" with reference to *What is basic about totaling a car*?
- **Thought**: He "*totally ruined most of the important parts*" of his car in
  the accident.
- **Interpretation**: The car is ***mostly*** totaled, an idiomatic use of *total*. [ODO vt.2](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/total)

---

***approximate interpretation*** is the name of this phenomenon:

***[approximate](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/approximate)*** ODO

> ADJECTIVE
>
> Close to the actual, but not completely accurate or exact:

[***interpretation***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/interpretation) WNWD (1960)

> 2. explanation; meaning; translation; exposition

The writer *approximates* the meaning in his mind by using a word. Understanding that there would be many appropriate adverbial queries, the reader *interprets* an *approximate* meaning from the usage. *Approximate interpretation* is the reason our conversations can be so interesting--even intense.

Answer (score 3):

1. Yes, there's a term for it. It's called [Semantic Bleaching](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/very-actually-and-other-examples-of-semantic-bleaching).
2. These adverbs are correct in that they are grammatical and no native speaker would find them unusual, unnatural, or hard to understand. As for it being good style, there's nothing elegant about phrases like "in a basic manner. In general, using more semantically dense verbs makes clunky adverbs or adverbial phrases unnecessary. "The food was good in a reasonable way" is awful, "The food was reasonably good" is fine but casual and squishy, and "The food sufficed" is lovely.

Answer (score 1):

The wording of your question suggests that manner adverbs are somehow more normal or central than other sorts of adverb.  I see no reason to think that is true. There are at least three theories about the syntactic types of adverbs:

- containing constituent (see [Thomason & Stalnaker](https://www.jstor.org/stable/4177764?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) and also Zeno Vendler), where manner adverbs are taken to be within verb phrases
- modified constituent (see [McCawley, chapter 19](https://books.google.com/books?id=k6-C5AWWqjQC&q=domain%20adverb#v=snippet&q=domain%20adverb&f=false)), where manner adverbs are taken to modify verb phrases
- grammatical relation (see [me](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/17271/how-can-psg-describe-the-vertical-dimension-of-sentence-structure)), where manner adverbs are taken to have the same grammatical relation as direct objects

In all three theories, there are other types of adverbs as well, and manner adverbs do not have a special privileged status.  Also, in all three, the same -ly word can sometimes have several different interpretations, depending on the type of adverb it is.

Answer (score -2):

I have found, especially in advertising, where people take great liberty to twist sentences with such words, presumably, to deceive and increase sales.
ie... purporting that an item is 'virtually free' when in fact 'NOT free' would be correct.
also... saying that their product is 'essentially pure/safe/etc' when further inspection reveals percentages of impurities, NOT safe for children/nursing mothers/...
These usages, or rather mis-usages indicate to me that these adverbs and their many synonyms
https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/another-word-for/essentially.html
can be replaced with the word 'NOT' in every circumstance to determine the truth.

I agree with Richard West  "It's called Semantic Bleaching."... but moreso, "Hyperbole? Slang? Butchering of the language?" – anongoodnurse Dec 26 '14 at 20:58

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question, as advertising uses language in very specific ways. 'Not' does not take into account the subtlety of word use in adverts (their meaning often distracting from or bending the truth, not blatantly contradicting it), and it especially can't be used in the OP's examples.